# How can I specify the function type in my type hints?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

How can I specify the type hint of a variable as a *function type*? There is no `typing.Function`, and I could not find anything in the relevant PEP, [PEP 483](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/).

Comment: A function is [`Callable`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/#fundamental-building-blocks)

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/#fundamental-building-blocks, last bullet point before "we might add".

Answer (score 847, accepted):

As [@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835179/how-can-i-specify-the-function-type-in-my-type-hints/39624147#comment63131590_37835179) noted in a comment, this can be done with [`typing.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/typing.html#typing.Callable):

```
from typing import Callable

def my_function(func: Callable):
```

**Note:** `Callable` on its own is equivalent to `Callable[..., Any]`.
Such a `Callable` takes *any* number and type of arguments (`...`) and returns a value of *any* type (`Any`). If this is too unconstrained, one may also specify the types of the input argument list and return type.

For example, given:

```
def sum(a: int, b: int) -> int: return a+b
```

The corresponding annotation is:

```
Callable[[int, int], int]
```

That is, the parameters are sub-scripted in the outer subscription with the return type as the second element in the outer subscription. In general:

```
Callable[[ParamType1, ParamType2, ..., ParamTypeN], ReturnType]
```

Comment: @javadba - oh, yes, but I'm still not sure on which dial... By the way - what about `Callable[[Arg, Types, Here], ...]` for `*args`, `**kwargs`, keyword-only args and positional only args? Have they not thought about calling convention in the type signatures for callables? ;)

Comment: [According to the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable), `typing.Callable` seems to be in favor of `collections.abc.Callable`:

Comment: more info at https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cheat_sheet_py3.html

Comment: Note that this is not quite the same thing. A function is a Callable but the programmer might be interested in specific attributes of functions, such as their unique dunder methods.

Comment: since all methods take `self` as a parameter, is the answer any different for methods?

Comment: nit: the parameters aren't subscripted, that's just a list literal...

Comment: Is it possible to give variable names along with datatypes in type hints?

Answer (score 21):

Another interesting point to note is that you can use the built in function `type()` to get the type of a built in function and use that.
So you could have

```
def f(my_function: type(abs)) -> int:
    return my_function(100)
```

Or something of that form

Comment: A type hint can be whatever you wish, but they haven't always been lazy evaluated. Also, does your function really only take `builtin_function_or_method` as `my_function`? Wouldn't a `lambda` work? A user defined function or bound method?

Comment: No you cannot, when running `mypy`, this gives the error: `error: Invalid type comment or annotation` `note: Suggestion: use type[...] instead of type(...)`.

Comment: note that `type(abs)` is just `builtin_function_or_method`... which i doubt very many things understand (ignoring the fact that it doesn't specify args, and ignoring the fact it's not even correct for this case)

Comment: This is not a valid type hint. It is a valid annotation (all expressions are), but no standard type checker will do anything useful with this.

Answer (score 20):

My specific use case for wanting this functionality was to enable rich code completion in PyCharm. Using `Callable` didn't cause PyCharm to suggest that the object had a `.__code__` attribute, which is what I wanted, in this case.

I stumbled across the `types` module and..

`from types import FunctionType`

allowed me to annotate an object with `FunctionType` and, voilà, PyCharm now suggests my object has a `.__code__` attribute.

The OP wasn't clear on why this type hint was useful to them. Callable certainly works for anything that implements `.__call__()` but for further interface clarification, I submit the `types` module.

Bummer that Python needed two very similar modules.

Comment: Conversely Pylance in vscode accept only `Callable` and not `FunctionType` as valid.