# How to specify input type function

Tags: python, python-3.x

To write a maintainable code, it's a good practice to specify the input and output types as below.

```
def hash_a(item: object, x: int, y: int) -> int:
    return x + y
```

My question is how we can specify function type as the input type ? For an example,

```
def hash_a(funct: object, x: int, y: int) -> int:
"""
funct : is a fuction
"""
        return x + y
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I specify the function type in my type hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835179/how-can-i-specify-the-function-type-in-my-type-hints)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`typing.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) as follows:

```
from typing import Callable

def hash_a(funct: Callable, x: int, y: int) -> int:
    ...
```

If you want to be more precise and specify the input/output types you can use `Callable` as a generic type as follows:

```
def hash_a(funct: Callable[[<arg_type_1>, <arg_type_2>, ..., <arg_type_n>], <output_type>], x: int, y: int) -> int:
    ...
```

whete `<arg_type_1>`, `<arg_type_2>` and `<arg_type_n>` represent the signature of your callable.

If you only care about the output type, you can specify an ellipsis as input types:

```
def hash_a(funct: Callable[..., <output_type>], x: int, y: int) -> int:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `typing.Callable[[int], int]`, where the first `[int]` is the type(s) of the argument(s), and the second `int` is the return type of the function.