# Can an object have a `Callable` type hint without specifying input arguments and return value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

The following code...

```
import typing
func:typing.Callable[[int, float], str]
```

Annotates `func` as a callable accepting two inputs. The two inputs are an `int` and a `float`. It also indicates that the return value is a string.

Is it possible to type hint something as a callable without specifying input argument types or output type?

For example:

```
def decorator(f:Callable):
    def _(*args, **kwargs)
        r = f(*map(str, args), **kwargs)
        return r
    return _
```

Comment: What do you mean by "possible"?

Comment: An answer to your question can be found here: [How can I specify the function type in my type hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835179/how-can-i-specify-the-function-type-in-my-type-hints)

Answer (score 4):

The `typing` module explicitly states you can use `...` in place of the signature, thought the return type seems mandatory.

> It is possible to declare the return type of a callable without specifying the call signature by substituting a literal ellipsis for the list of arguments in the type hint: `Callable[..., ReturnType]`.

`Callable[..., Any]` would appear to be equivalent to your requested `Callable` annotation.

Comment: To wit, `mypy` already recognizes `Callable` in a type hint as `Callable[..., Any]`

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

> a bare Callable in an annotation is equivalent to Callable[..., Any]
> -- [PEP-0484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/)