# Is there a way in Python to ensure that one argument of my function is another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

type annotation in the function arguments definition:
I want to implement a High Order Function in python, and for that I would like to have explicit arguments type. Is there a way to show a 'function' type?

```
def high_order_math(a: Float, b: Float, func: function):
    return func(a,b)
```

---

Here are some findings, appreciate you all that have shared your knowledge

```
def high_order_math(a: float, b: float, func: Callable[[float, float], float]) -> float:
     return func(a, b)

high_order_math(1,2,3)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

File "", line 2, in high_order_math

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: Are you asking about *type annotation* or runtime type checking?

Comment: Basically it's not really necessary to implement a try except block, since as @Samwise also said. Python interpreter do this checks. This type annotation can be used for both cases.

Comment: Who said anything about a try-except block? Again, **what exactly are you asking?** Are you asking how *to write a type annotation for a function*? Or are you asking how to check the type of an object is a function at runtime?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, the question was about type annotation in the function arguments definition. Of course, by the *reading* the question u can see that I know how to write a type annotation, I just didn't know it for cases such as high order functions. Doesn't matter who asked about try-exception, it's just the most basic way to deal with runtime problems for each modern programming language. Look, there are 2 following answers bellow. Both answers can be useful, considering the exact cases you've mentioned. The problem was solved. Have fun! 
To check types use python built-in `type(func)`

Answer (score 8):

Use the `Callable` type from `typing`.  The `Callable` type is a generic so you can specify the signature of the function.

```
from typing import Callable

def high_order_math(a: float, b: float, func: Callable[[float, float], float]) -> float:
    return func(a, b)
```

Comment: This doesn't actually enforce anything at runtime.

Comment: The Python interpreter will automatically raise a `TypeError` exception at runtime if you try to invoke `func` and it is not a callable; it's not necessary to do anything special to get that behavior.  In the context of a question about typing it's generally understood that what we're interested in is being able to detect the error ahead of time via static analysis aided by type annotations.

Comment: The context of the quesiton is *not clear*. That is the point I'm making. In either case, really, this question is a duplicate. But it is unclear what the OP expects, it wouldn't e the first quesiton asked assuming type annotations work like variable declarations that will catch problems at compile time, or even some assume at run time.

Comment: It was adequately clear to me from OP's use of the phrase "explicit type" and their placeholder attempt at type annotations.  If I got it wrong, I trust that OP will ask for clarification.  :)

Comment: If that was *adequately clear* then *someone with your experience and rep* should have seen that this was a clear duplicate. [This would generally be the canonical duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835179/how-can-i-specify-the-function-type-in-my-type-hints). Really, either way it is a duplicate. I understand that it's not always obvious, but it's always worth to check these sorts of questions

Answer (score 1):

You've received a good answer, but inside the function body you can verify is the argument passed is callable:

```
def high_order_math(a: float, b: float, func):
    if not callable(func):
        raise TypeError
    else:
        print(a + b)
```

```
high_order_math(1, 2, lambda x, y: x + y) # works because it's callable
```

```
high_order_math(1, 2, 'hello') # raises error because it's not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> def high_order_math(a, b, func):
...     if callable(func):
...         return func(a, b)
...     raise TypeError(f"{type(func)} is not a function or callable")
... 
>>> high_order_math(3, 4, lambda a,b: a+b)
7
```

Comment: That looks a lot like my answer

Comment: Well, sorry. I didn't copy you

Comment: @NicolasGervais that isn't exactly a implausible coincidence, this is the idiomatic way to check for callables... indeed, depending one what the OP is asking, this question should definitely be closed as a duplicate

Comment: It is a nice aspect of python. And it is even nicer to just call it and raise exception when we need to use it. It is one of python's most appealing features.