# require function for parameter python

Tags: python, function, parameters

So I decided I wanted to make my own custom event system thing and it all works except that on line 2 python is like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\CollidaCube\VSCode\GameAPY\event.py", line 1, in <module>
    class EventListener():
  File "d:\CollidaCube\VSCode\GameAPY\event.py", line 2, in EventListener
    def __init__(self, func: function):
NameError: name 'function' is not defined
```

why is this and how can i fix it? [my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7zhT.png)

Comment: ignore the highlight in the picture. it doesn't mean anything

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835179/how-can-i-specify-the-function-type-in-my-type-hints) answer your question?

Comment: yes actually yes it does. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Seon has responded with a valid answer to my question. This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835179/how-can-i-specify-the-function-type-in-my-type-hints). In my case, I have decided to use `type(abs)`. its simple and I understand it.

Edit:
After some experimentation I discovered that my VSCode nor python will yell at me if I do `type[abs]`.