# Type hint callback function with optional parameters (aka Callable with optional parameter)

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I specify the type of a callback function which takes an optional parameter?

For example, I have the following function:

```
def getParam(param: str = 'default'):
  return param
```

I'd like to pass it on as a callback function and use it both as `Callable[[str], str]` *and* `Callable[[], str]`:

```
def call(callback: Callable[[<???>], str]):
  return callback() + callback('a')
```

What do I write for `<???>`? I've tried Python's `Optional` but that does not work, as it still enforces a parameter (even if with value `None`) to be present.

---

For reference, I'm basically searching for the equivalent of the following TypeScript:

```js
function call(callback: (a?: string) => string) {
  return callback() + callback('a');
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I specify the function type in my type hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835179/how-can-i-specify-the-function-type-in-my-type-hints)

Comment: You just want a callable with no arguments - the fact that `getParam` achieves that by having one parameter but with a default value is completely irrelevant to `call`: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=15accb9eb5f0a2d7b0d2bf00c54cd1c1. (Same [in TS](https://tsplay.dev/W4XQAW), for that matter.)

Comment: @jonrsharpe My example was too abbreviated. I edited the code, so the `call` function would use both ways.

Comment: I think you want an intersection type, something that's both a `Callable[[str], str]` _and_ `Callable[[], str]`, but Python typing only supports unions.

Comment: Have you considered simply *requiring* an argument, and letting the caller pass `'default'` explicitly instead? `def call(callback: Callable[[str], str]): return callback('default') + callback('a')`. The circumstances under which a callback is used don't usually require the flexibility you are looking for.

Comment: As an alternative, use `def getParam(param: str = None)`, and let the callback replace `None` with the true default *inside* the function. Then you can truthfully say the type of `getParam` is `Callable[[Optional[str]], str]`.

Comment: @chepner but MyPy won't actually let you call a `Callable[[Optional[str]], str]` without any arguments: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=50d1b1d2bd809ebdac33cfc6d59c8b63 ([_"this is not the same concept as an optional argument"_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional)).

Comment: The *caller* is perfectly capable of writing `callback(None)` instead of `callback()`. Optional arguments for more for the benefit of lazy human typists.

Comment: @chepner Valid workaround! I'm concerned with the noise `None` is producing.

Comment: What noise is that?

Comment: @chepner `callback()` is less cognitive load than `callback(None)`

Comment: On who? Nobody calls `callback` explicitly.

Comment: @chepner IMO this will be a pointless subjective discussion on *why I believe so* and *you believe otherwise*. Let's skip that. But apart from that, I think your suggestion would also make a nice answer as a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is no syntax to indicate optional or keyword arguments
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable

However you can use something like this

```py
from typing import Protocol


class MyCallback(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, x: int =5): ...


def foo(callback: MyCallback):
    callback()  # <- IDE is fine with both of these lines
    callback(7)
```

Comment: This is interesting, but won't recognise that `getParam` implements `MyCallback` without further information: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=4c92d1bcf457e3a37f4aa20e82d41e4b

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Unlike with `Callable`, you need to make sure the argument names match.

Comment: @user2357112 oh interesting - this answer would benefit from an example that actually applies to the OP's case

Comment: (You can mark the argument as positional-only in the protocol to remove the name match requirement.)