# Enforcing a function signature in Python

Tags: python, inheritance

I am building a fairly large class that calculates certain parameters. This is a simple version of it:

```
class MainClass():

    self.processes = {}
    def __init__(self):
        self.processes = self.build_dictionary()

    def build_dictionary(self):
        return {
            'p1' : self.Process1,
            'p2' : self.Process2,
            'p3' : self.Process3
        }

    def Process1(self, data):
        return data
    
    def Process2(self, data):
        return data
    
    def Process3(self, data):
        return data
    
    def run(self):
        values = [1, 2, 3]
        for v in values:
            for p, method in self.processes.items():
                print(f'{p} : {method(v)}')

mc = MainClass()
mc.run()
```

It has a dictionary of all methods that have to be applied to some data. They each need a string key as the results are later loaded into a dictionary/database.
I would like to enforce or imply some structure to these ProcessN methods, since they all need to have the same arguments and return types for my system to work.
I keep thinking about using abstract classes and inheritance in some way, but it feels like I would be overcomplicating things, since some of these methods are pretty short and creating a new class for each feels like needlessly overcrowding the namespace.

Any suggestions on how to imply a function signature?

**EDIT for clarity:** I specifically want to define a common signature for my methods, like:

```
generic_process(self, data : int) -> int
```

That would help guide future development. Similar to how defining an abstract class creates an implied structure to all future classes. A solution I would like to avoid could be:

```
class Process(abc):
    @abstractmethod
    def run(data : int): -> int
        pass

class Process1(Process):
    def run(data : int): -> int
        return data
# ETC
```

Then rewrite my main class to use these new processes, calling run. But I'm wondering if there's a simpler way of achieving the same result.

Comment: I have no idea what you asked, and how question title matches with ur question

Comment: I _could_ conceive of this being a question about how to define a type signature for a function that takes an argument `data` (of some specific type) and returns a value `data` (potentially of some other type) and then asserts that a bunch of functions all fit that signature; but if that's what's intended, it should be a much more specific question. ([How can I specify the function type in my type hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835179/how-can-i-specify-the-function-type-in-my-type-hints) might be a starting place).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't think I agree with duplicates. Reading the question it seems to be about implying they all have **common** signature. None of linked duplicates answer that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy "I would like to enforce or imply some structure to these ProcessN methods, since they all need to have the same arguments and return types for my system to work." this, at least for me, quite clearly implies what this question is specifically about.

Comment: @matszwecja, I've added some additional duplicate links.

Comment: Yep, now I agree.

Comment: @Mauro - do your `ProcessN` functions use/need `self` argument in any way?

Comment: They do, this is a  simplified example

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can use function annotations to imply or document the expected signature of your methods. While function annotations don't enforce the signature, they serve as a form of documentation and can be used by tools like linters or static analyzers to provide warnings or suggestions.

Here's an example of how you can add function annotations to your `ProcessN` methods:

```py
class MainClass():
    processes = {}

    def __init__(self):
        self.processes = self.build_dictionary()

    def build_dictionary(self):
        return {
            'p1': self.Process1,
            'p2': self.Process2,
            'p3': self.Process3
        }

    def Process1(self, data: int) -> int:
        return data

    def Process2(self, data: int) -> int:
        return data

    def Process3(self, data: int) -> int:
        return data

    def run(self):
        values = [1, 2, 3]
        for v in values:
            for p, method in self.processes.items():
                print(f'{p} : {method(v)}')

mc = MainClass()
mc.run()
```

Comment: I don't see the point of having a `MainClass.processes` as a class variable separate from the `self.processes` instance variable. If you want a type declaration at the class level, that's what `processes: dict` is for.

Comment: Typehints are useful, but I was hoping for a stricter implementation, like how declaring an abstract class can help guide future developers by provinding a predefined structure. I guess there aren't any similar tools in python